# Monthly repeating event for Monday before 1st Tuesday of a month in Google Calendar

Tags: calendar, rrule

I need to set up a repeating (monthly) event for the Monday preceding the first Tuesday of a Month in Google Calendar. There's no way to create this directly using the calendar app/web interface itself. Can anyone come up with an RRULE that will accomplish this? If so I can import the entry from there.
Thanks

I've tried everything I can think of.